# Unregistering the BackgroundTask of a closed Application

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

Since I need to pass some values from my Application into my BackgroundTask, I use a little different setting for registration. Instead of setting an EntryPoint, I leave it empty, which enables me of passing the values.

As common, I added the BackgroundTask into my appxmanifest, how ever, without the EntryPoint, the start of an BackgroundTask triggers **OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)** in **App.xaml.cs** from where I call a custom **static Start(args.TaskInstance, value1, value2)** of my BackgroundTask.
**Start()** takes the recent TaskInstance as well as the custom-values and calls a custom **Run()** which also takes custom-values. The BackgroundTask runs as expected and in the end calls the common **Run()** method of my BackgroundTask which calls **GetDeferral.Complete()** for updating my UI, this is how it looks in code.

**My BackgroundTask Registration**

```
public async static Task RegisterMainBackgroundTask()
{
    BackgroundAccessStatus backgroundAccessStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
    BackgroundTaskBuilder mainTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
    { Name = "MainTask" };
    mainTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
    MainBackgroundTask = mainTaskBuilder.Register();

    if(backgrundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedToSystemPolicy)
        RequestLocationAccess();
    else
        NoAccessNotification();
}

public static void StartupRegisterTasks()
{
    if (MainBackgroundTask != null)
    {
        MainBackgroundTask.Completed -= new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundTaskOnCompleted);
        MainBackgroundTask.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundTaskOnCompleted);
    }
}

public static void UnregisterOldBackgroundTasks()=>
    BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Where(x => x.Value.Name == "MainTask").ToList().ForEach(x=>x.Value.Unregister(true));
```

**In App.xaml.cs:**

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    BackgroundTask.LocalBackgroundWorker.UnregisterOldBackgroundTasks();
    Task.Run(async()=>await BackgroundTask.LocalBackgroundWorker.RegisterMainBackgroundTask()).Wait();
    BackgroundTask.LocalBackgroundWorker.StartupRegisterTasks();
}

protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args) =>
    MainBackgroundTask.Start(args.TaskInstance, value1, value2);
```

**In BackgroundTask.cs**

```
public static void Start(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance, Guid client, Guid company) =>
    new MainBackgroundTask().Run(taskInstance, value1, value2);

public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance, Guid value1, Guid value2)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await RunBackgroundProcess(taskInstance, value1, value2)).Wait();
    Run(taskInstance);
}

private static TransferService.DataTransfer transfer => 
    new TransferService.DataTransfer();
private async Task RunMainBackgroundProcess(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance, Guid value1, Guid value2)
{
    await transfer.SendJob(value1, value2);
    await transfer.UpdateGeoLocation(taskInstance, value1, value2);
}

public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance) =>
    taskInstance.GetDeferral().Complete();
```

**My ApplicationStructure is as below:**

- ProjectSolution
- BackgroundTask (Contains BackgroundTask.cs)
- MyApplication (Contains App.xaml.cs and BackgroundTaskRegistration)
- TransferService (Contains Transfer.cs)

As long as my App is running or at least minimized, my BackgroundTask behaves as expected, but as soon as the app is closed, the BackgroundTask runs into an Error. Sadly the only information I get is from **unhandlederror.log** and says

> 2018-06-05T09:53:01    ErrorMessage    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Since it's impossible to me debugging a closed App, I can't determine, where the error happens. I guess, calling the TransferService while the App is closed is impossible, so I'm searching for an EntryPoint where I can unregister the BackgroundTask when it is called the first time while the App is closed. UWP makes no difference between suspending and closing on app-level, so sadly I can't unregister it, when closing the app.
Any help in solving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get that exception every time the app is closed? Could you please try to unregister the background task inside `Suspending` event handle?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/suspend-an-app

Comment: Sure I could unregister the task in OnSuspending, but this would stop it to run when the app is minimized. What I did so far is changing the Task to a OneShot-Task and unregistering/reregistering it every time it ran correctly. So it only runs into an error once. Still it would be great, if it could even run when the app is closed. On the other hand, I managed to hide the error-message, so the customer doesn't recognize the single error after the app is closed, thats fine, since I run the Task (or at least what it does) after the app restarts.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Did you mean you have resolved?  And could you please check if [Postpone app suspension with extended execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) can help  ?